# How to get value from a php array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Sorry, its a simple question but difficult for me as I am a new php developer. I have an array $thread_template, which is generated dynamically. When I print this array using print_r function, it gives

```
 BP_Messages_Thread_Template Object
(
    [current_message] => 3
    [message_count] => 4
    [message] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 73 // I want to get this id.
            [thread_id] => 63
            [sender_id] => 289
            [subject] => Re: This is an anonymous message about a dino
            [message] => this message is second reply from family member.
            [date_sent] => 2014-05-05 13:25:10
            [anonymous] => 
        ) .... and so on
```

I want to get get id at line# 6. I am using

```
$thread_template->$message->id;
```

I also used

```
$thread_template[message][id];
```

both are not working. How can I get an id?

Comment: Try `$thread_template->message->id;`

Comment: As a first step, [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393). And you don't include `$` when accessing property values. Just use `$thread_template->message->id`.

Comment: You're dealing with objects, not arrays

Comment: Glad we could help you. If you feel an answer solved your problem, please [mark it as 'accepted'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are not dealing with an array, but with an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (`$thread_template`), and you're trying to access one of it's [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). You don't need the dollar sign (`$`) to access property names.

So, assuming that the properties are [public](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), use:

```
$thread_template->message->id;
```

(If they're not public, you'll need to use a method that returns the value of the property. Without looking at the code, I can't tell you wether that's the case and if so, which method you need to use)

As you might have noticed by now, the object `$thread_template` contains a number of properties, including `message` that is an object of itself, too. The `message` object contains a number of properties as well, including the `id` property (which is the one we're looking for).

#### Is there a situation where I *should* use a dollar sign in property names?

Only if you want to call a property whose name is saved in a variable. For instance:

```
$propertyName = 'fooBar';
echo $myObject->$propertyName;
```

is the same as:

```
echo $myObject->fooBar;
```

(but this is just a sidenote, normally you won't have to do this)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an array, it's an object, try:

```
$thread_template->message->id
```